# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'] was not found in any of following sources

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

When I tried to refresh Gradle project , I encountered this error:

> Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'] was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

How to solve this issue?

[image: details pic]

Comment: please do not use pics to show your code, insert it as "code block" in your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just forgot to specify the plugin version, which is mandatory for "not Core" plugins:

For example :

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.10"
}
```

See:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.html

Comment: thks man , perhaps I mistakenly , but in my impression the plugin version specified at last night . At least I remembered that i've tried that , although it went wrong obviously .  ...  well , I specified the plugin version just now ,and it was solved anyway.